# Andrioid Drawer Menu like custom menu on clickListener

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, onclicklistener

I am working on a `Google Maps V2` application, in which my `MainActivity` has a `Fragment` for Maps and a `linear layout` which holds this fragment. I also draw markers on the map. My idea is to create a menu like [Drawermenu](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) which will show custom Menu for that `Clicked Marker`..

I am a bit new to android, and so far, what I know is, I can implement a Drawer Menu for Complete application as a navigation (have read the documentation and a few articles on this and I can do it myself now).

My Question is, can I build a drawer menu which will be shown `onMarkerClickListener` ??

is that something possible??

is someone has done it already? any code example of SO or github??

any rough algo / code example / guideline is highly appreciated...

thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to prevent drawer from listening to gestures use.

```
final DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
drawer.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
```

and use openDrawer and closeDrawer to change menu visibility.

```
//and then use it in your onMarkerClickListener.
drawer.openDrawer(Your View, Usually a ListView);
```

and if you want to hide drawer use.

```
drawer.closeDrawer(Your View, Usually a ListView);
```

I hope this will help you :)

Comment: seems like a good idea, let me try it... gonna update you over this soon